# Kubernetes how to run container only after volume(nfs) is mounted

Tags: nginx, docker, kubernetes

The official nginx image does not start on my setup because I am mounting the config files from this nfs volume.I am trying overcome this with a bash script like below, but it is not working. Any suggestions?  `kubectl logs conteinerxxx -p`  returns `nginx: invalid option: "off"`. But `nginx -g "daemon off;"`seems to run nice on my shell. Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this? BTW this is a coreos cluster on DigitalOcean.

## dockerfile

```
//REPLACE THE OLD `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`
ADD nginxinit.sh /nginxinit.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./nginxinit.sh"]
```

## bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
until mountpoint -q /etc/nginx; do
    echo "$(date) - wainting for NGINX config files to be mounted..."
    sleep 1
done

nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

## RC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: mypod
  labels:
    name: mypod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: mypod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mypod
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: cescoferraro/nginx
          name: myfrontend
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/etc/nginx"
            name: nginx-nfs
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-nfs
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nginx-nfs
```

## PV

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nginx-nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 32Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    # FIXME: use the right IP
    server: x.x.x.x
    path: "/nginx"
```

## PVC

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-nfs
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 32Mi
```

Comment: Since you are mounting the config files from an external volume, wouldn't it be easier to just put the "daemon off" part in the config ? Or maybe add it afterwards, like: `echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` ?

Comment: Yeah! I am pretty sure this problem is resolvable with bash although I have not put much effort into it. I was wondering if there isnt a Kubernetes way to deal with this kind of situation. I will try to use daemon off on the nginx config file. Currently I am using a nginx config that I 'docker cp' to my nfs volume.

Comment: Hi @CESCO, the pod should not be started until after the volume is mounted -- if not, that's a bug.  How often can you reproduce this issue?

Comment: @PaulMorie The was a roblem with the way I have copied the nginx files. `"docker cp containerxxx:/etc/nginx/* /tmp" `did not copied the conf.d directory (dumb me). so I fixed it and it all worked with my image. I though it would work with the official image but it did not. I looks reproducible using the nginx image

Answer (score 0):

Better to put configs into configMap

```
      volumeMounts:
        - name: nfsvol
          mountPath: /srv/nfs/share
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /etc/nginx
  volumes:
    - name: nfsvol
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: nfs-pvc
    - name: config-volume
      projected:
        sources:
        - configMap:
            name: core-nginx-config
            items:
             - key: fastcgi_params
               path: fastcgi_params
             - key: mime.types
               path: mime.types
             - key: nginx.conf
               path: nginx.conf
```